# Plot array of Figures Mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia

I have a function that creates a figure and now I would like to call this function repeatedly inside a loop with different parameters, collect the figures and plot them.
This is how I would do it in julia:

```
using Plots

plots = Array{Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend},2}(undef, 3,3)

for i in 1:3
    for j in 1:3
        plots[i,j] = scatter(rand(10), rand(10))
        title!(plots[i,j], "Plot $(i),$(j)")
    end
end

plot(plots..., layout=(3,3))
```

However I have to write python. So currently I have a function that creates a new figure and returns it. I would be reluctant to change this function call signature (eg. to pass some axis object), since it is allready used in a different context. This is a minimal working example. For some reason the individual figures are displayed here even though I am not calling `plt.display()`, in the main code they are not however. Here the final figure is empty.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,3)

def plottingfunction(x,y):
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    return plt.gcf()

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        x = np.random.rand(10)
        y = np.random.rand(10)
        ax[i,j] = plottingfunction(x,y)

plt.show()
```

So how do I plot allready existing functions in a grid, that are for example collected inside of an array using python matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

How about making the `ax` parameter optional, so you can use it for this but do not break your existing use-case?

```
def plottingfunction(x, y, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        # Set up a new figure and axes
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    else:
        fig = ax.get_figure()

    # Plot the data
    ax.scatter(x, y)
    
    return fig
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can play around with setting/getting the current axis. It doesn't make much sense to me to do it this way, but it *seems* to work for this minimal example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3)


def plottingfunction(x, y):
    axis = plt.gca()
    axis.scatter(x, y)


for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        plt.sca(ax[i, j])
        x = np.random.rand(10)
        y = np.random.rand(10)
        plottingfunction(x, y)


plt.show()
```

**EDIT:** It pains me to do this, but this works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(3, 3)
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(3, 3)


def plottingfunction1(x, y):
    axis = plt.gca()
    axis.scatter(x, y)


def plottingfunction2(x, y):
    axis = plt.gca()
    axis.plot(x, y)


for ax_ind in range(0, 9):
    x = np.random.rand(10)
    y = np.random.rand(10)

    plt.sca(fig1.axes[ax_ind])
    plottingfunction1(x, y)

    plt.sca(fig2.axes[ax_ind])
    plottingfunction2(x, y)
```

**EDIT 2:** Create figures and axes as needed, pass the axes to the plotting functions..

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def plottingfunction1(x, y, axis):
    axis.scatter(x, y)


def plottingfunction2(x, y, axis):
    axis.plot(x, y)


_, ax1 = plt.subplots(3, 3)
_, ax2 = plt.subplots(3, 3)

for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        x = np.random.rand(10)
        y = np.random.rand(10)

        plottingfunction1(x, y, axis=ax1[i, j])
        plottingfunction2(x, y, axis=ax2[i, j])

plottingfunction2(x, y, axis=ax1[1, 2])
```

Comment: Okay, this is allready a step in the right direction, I guess. However I am plotting a lot of different things (eg. I have multiple plotingfunctions that are plotting seperate histograms etc.), so I am creating a new figure to isolate the different plotting functions. If I remove it, everything will be plotted on top of each other, all inside of one figure. But if I try your solution and I leave it in, I just get a bunch of empty plots.

Comment: See updated answer. But honestly, depending on how complex the end result needs to be, I think you'll be better off shifting the code towards a more Python-friendly paradigm.

Comment: Okay, how would the more python friendly paradigm look like in this case?

Comment: Creating figures and axes, and passing the axes to the plotting functions would likely make anything you're trying to do easier. See edit 2.